# Multiple Simultaneous file writes with HMC4 on Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, locking, mutual-exclusion

I am using Hosted Messaging and Collaboration v4.0 on Classic ASP. My website can have multiple instances depending on how many users are currently logged in. When ever this HMC4 is being used, it logs everything by creating a text file. There is only 1 text file per day, and all HMC4 instances must access this single file to log the usage.

Once in a while I get the error `Access to path **** is denied`. I have all the permissions set, so the problem is most likely when multiple instances of the application try to write to the log file at the same time.

I am lost at how to fix this, modifying the logging method is impossible since HMC4 is a Microsoft's product and I don't have source code for it, and handling the exception is not an ideal option since I will have to modify the code +70 times across the website.

Any ideas? Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300678/how-can-i-determine-if-a-file-is-locked-using-vbs

Comment: can you show you code how you writting to text file? are you using OpenAsTextStream or OpenTextFile?

Comment: That's not possible, HMC4 is a 3rd Party component, I don't have source code for it.